# No exact matches in call to instance method 'append' in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Tried to combine or merging two model to one model
1st model = items [ InboxModel]. (My own Inbox)
2nd model = items2 [MoInboxModel] (SDK Inbox)

1st + 2nd -> combinedItems

```
private var items: [InboxModel] = []
private var items2: [MoInboxModel] = []
private var combinedItems: [combinedInboxModel] = []

struct InboxModel {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}

struct MoInboxModel {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}

struct combinedInboxModel {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}

self?.combinedItems.append(self?.items). //No exact matches in call to instance method 'append
self?.combinedItems.append(contentsOf: self?.items2 ?? []) //No exact matches in call to instance method 'append
```

Why there is an error while merge it ? How to merge it correctly?

Comment: Hi, as per your code you can't, but there is a way to do it using "associatedtype", I never tried. Or you can do as @Paulw11 suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You have three unrelated types - `InboxModel`, `MoInboxModel` and `combinedInboxModel` (Which should be `CombinedInboxModel`.  Even though they all have properties with the same name, they are different types.

There is no `append` function on an array of `combinedInboxModel` that accepts an array of `InboxModel` or `MoInboxModel`.

You could use `map` on each of your two input arrays to convert them to an array of `CombinedInboxModel` which you can then put into `combinedItems`.

Presumably you are writing this code in a closure, which is why you have a `weak self`.  Best to deal with that first and then process your arrays.

```
guard let self = self else {
    return
}

self.combinedItems = self.items.map { CombinedInboxModel(id:$0.id,title:$0.title,message:$0.message,date:$0.date) }

let items2 = self.items2.map { CombinedInboxModel(id:$0.id,title:$0.title,message:$0.message,date:$0.date) }

self.combinedItems.append(contentsOf:items2)
```

You haven't shown where `items` and `items2` come from; Is it possible just to fetch them as instances of the same struct to start with?

Comment: So i need to do 

combinedItems = items.map,,  

combinedItems += items2.map ?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you have three structs with the same properties is a bit fishy. I would consider a different design if I were you.

However, if you must go with this approach, you might want to consider starting with a protocol and getting rid of the `combinedInboxModel` struct.

```
protocol InboxModelable {
    var id: String { get }
    var title: String { get }
    var message: String { get }
    var date: Date { get }
}
```

Now make your two structs conform to `InboxModelable`.

```
struct InboxModel: InboxModelable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}

struct MoInboxModel: InboxModelable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    let date: Date
}
```

Since both of your types conform to `InboxModelable` you can directly store both types in an array of type `Array<InboxModelable>` without having to map the elements.

```
class SomeClass {
    private var items: [InboxModel] = []
    private var items2: [MoInboxModel] = []
    private var combinedItems: [InboxModelable] = []

    func combineItems() {
        doSomething { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.combinedItems.append(contentsOf: self.items)
            self.combinedItems.append(contentsOf: self.items2)
        }
    }
}
```